# Realm Database Cross Platform Compatibility?

Tags: java, android, swift, ios8, realm

Could a 'realm' be created by Realm Java and be read by Realm for iOS(8)? How cross platform compatible is the Realm Databasing system? I have an idea for a mobile app where I would like to create a 'realm' with a standard java class -- possibly a behind the scene function to a web site -- and then have the mobile app retrieve the 'realm' and read its data. (I hope that made sense.)

Comment: They all rely on the `Realm-Core`, so realms made by a core that supports the same file format can read each others' realm files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely!

Providing the model object class definitions are the same on both platforms, it's entirely possible to move a Realm file between an iOS device and an Android device (and vice versa) and properly read/write to them! :)

*(Disclaimer: I work for Realm.)*

Comment: Thank you. I intend to experiment with using Realm in a java class file.

Comment: TiM do you know when Realm will update their framework so it will work in Xcode 7.1.1? I get the message: "Module file was created by an older version of the compiler; rebuild 'RealSwift' and try again".

Comment: Is there a way to define your models once and use them on all platforms? "One point of truth"

Comment: @Colorado_mynydd_dyn I've seen that issue a few times before. It's not the framework's fault per sé (We should be already rebuilt for Xcode 7.2 at this point!), but it usually indicates a glitch occurred in CocoaPods/Carthage. USUALLY deleting the DerivedData folder and re-importing the dependency  fixes it. Let me know how you go!

Comment: @MartinO'Shea Short of manually rewriting the models in each language, our Realm Browser app has a basic feature where it can generate model files based off the configuration of the Realm file itself. Give that one a try! :)